# How to type function signature in TS?

Tags: typescript

How to type arguments for a function so they can be reusable, for example I have a function with signature `x,y`. I would like to re-use the type signature for similar function. Is it possible in TS?

```
function add(x: number, y: number): number {
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `type Fn = (x: number, y: number) => number;

const add: Fn = (x, y) => x + y;
const sub: Fn = (x, y) => x - y;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create custom type and reuse it:

```
type SomeFuncType = (x: number, y: number) => number;

const add: SomeFuncType = (a, b) => a + b;
const mul: SomeFuncType = (a, b) => a * b;

console.log(add(1, 3));
console.log(mul(1, 3));
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a similar question, maybe you could help me out there too. Thanks 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944226/how-to-re-use-arguments-signature-for-a-function-in-typescript