# How to re-use arguments signature for a function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a type signature for a function

```
type ExecCallbackType = (code: number, stdout: string, stderr: string, cmdType: CmdType) => void
```

I need to create a type signature for many function wherethese 3 arguments, code, stdout and stderr are always passed

here my "reusable" type:

```
export type ExecCallback = (
    code: number,
    stdout: string,
    stderr: string
) => any;
```

How to create a new type signature which can include on ExecCallback + cmdType:string

What I have tried with no success:

```
type ExecCallbackType = (ExecCallback & cmdType: CmdType) => void
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: maybe related? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: or intersection type https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html ??

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for -

```
type CmdType = {}

type ExecCallback = (
    code: number,
    stdout: string,
    stderr: string
) => any

type Param = Parameters<ExecCallback>

type Cons<H, T extends readonly any[]> =
    ((head: H, ...tail: T) => void) extends ((...cons: infer R) => void) ? R : never;

type Push<T extends readonly any[], V>
    = T extends any ? Cons<void, T> extends infer U ?
    { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : V } : never : never;

type FullParams = Push<Param, CmdType>
type ExecCallbackType = (...args: FullParams) => void
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgtgEwCrmgXigbwL4CheiRQCiAHhAMYwCGANrQEbUUDWUGAFLlD1BQPYIIALigA7AK5wGEAE4AabrwDOwBPwnBRq2QEsxAc0W8oqobNnbgew7gCU7AHxRqYkPkLQACtVnU47FA+fnAQwHLKADxklDT0TKyOHqiw-GJRABLyUEhQEKThYgjKULIQ1OpitCAubgDaALrOaEo8HBwAFuUIollQAHSDwNS6tKJIDmjOAG78uggO+YXFUO2D-QLpovoAZnJQAEqTM3MLUAD8h1CiYhDTcgDcyUReEsodkblLEEUlZRVpaq1ECNbIANSSJgwXwKPxWrhqlxgaSis3m2SQzm+vygu32AFULq0sFA6gBpXFiKAsCAgfg7KD4hqiCnYlY0ukM3KXJDkhrXKBgqDYAW3e6yUV3R7PaAAMQk9GC-hKGFe70iSrg2XgyFQSU8JHIVDojGYLBQRE4618BmUonlit8yuOUDRCFwQA)

Also, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546710/push-type-to-the-end-of-the-tuple) post for `Cons` and `Push`.